# C# EF Core: How to map One-to-Zero with multiple properties (with Attributes only) [With Workaround]?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Community,

I tried my first **Entity Framework Core** project. Now I am unable to map the properties in my models, these are **NOT One-to-One** relations, I would call it "One-to-Zero":

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UpdatedById")]
    public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeletedById")]
    public User DeletedBy { get; set; }

    // foreign keys
    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public int? DeletedById { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MailAdress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactDetailsByUserId")]
    public ContactDetails ContactDetailsByUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactDetailsByAdminId")]
    public ContactDetails ContactDetailsByAdmin { get; set; }

    // foreign keys
    public int? ContactDetailsByUserId { get; set; }
    public int? ContactDetailsByAdminId { get; set; }
}
```

So `ContactDetails` can have **three different Users**.

`User`can have **two different ContactDetails**.

If I try to create a migration for this, I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ContactDetails.CreatedBy' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I really want to do this with Attributes only, if this is possible, anyway with the **Fluent-API** this **works**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasOne(c => c.CreatedBy).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ContactDetails>(c => c.CreatedById).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasIndex(c => c.CreatedById).IsUnique(false);

    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasOne(c => c.UpdatedBy).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ContactDetails>(c => c.UpdatedById).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasIndex(c => c.UpdatedById).IsUnique(false);

    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasOne(c => c.DeletedBy).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ContactDetails>(c => c.DeletedById).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    builder.Entity<ContactDetails>().HasIndex(c => c.DeletedById).IsUnique(false);

    builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.ContactDetailsByUser).WithOne().HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.ContactDetailsByUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    builder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.ContactDetailsByUserId).IsUnique(false);

    builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.ContactDetailsByAdmin).WithOne().HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.ContactDetailsByAdminId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    builder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.ContactDetailsByAdminId).IsUnique(false);
}
```

Maybe the Fluent thing will help someone, but is it possible to do this with **Attributes only**?

Thanks for your time.

Best Regards

Stewie

Comment: These are not "one-to-zero", but unidirectional many-to-one. Anyway, the answer to your question is no. In EF Core many things can be done only via fluent API, so accept that fact and move on.

Comment: Did wait a bit, but yes, seems there are no solutions besides of flient API, thanks anyway ;)